# How to call C callback from Chicken Scheme

Tags: chicken-scheme

I'm writing a Chicken Scheme library that can eventually be used from C code. For this purpose, I define the entrypoint `my_entrypoint` from my Scheme code. `my_entrypoint` takes a C callback that does computations:

```scheme
(define-external (my_entrypoint ((function void (void)) compute)) void
  (let ([x (compute)])
    ...))

(return-to-host)
```

How can I adapt the line 2 so that my library builds and run correctly. As is, my code crashes with the following error log:

```
$ ./test

Error: call of non-procedure: #<pointer 0x10f47fb75>

    Call history:

    test.scm:5: return-to-host    
    test.scm:2: compute
```

Here is an example of C program that uses my library:

```c
#include <chicken.h>

int compute_something(void)
{
  return 42;
}

void my_entrypoint(void (*)(void));

int main()
{
  C_word k = CHICKEN_run(C_toplevel);
  (void)k;
  my_entrypoint(&compute_something);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't call a C function from Scheme that was passed as an argument. The simplest way would be do do it with a local foreign-lambda* to which you pass the function pointer, which can then do the actual calling:

```
(define-external (my_entrypoint ((function int ()) compute-raw)) void
  (let* ((call-proc (foreign-lambda* int (((function int ()) compute))
                      "C_return(compute());"))
         (x (call-proc compute)))
    ...))

(return-to-host)
```

Comment: It might actually make more sense to expose this as a regular C function. This then could call a Scheme procedure which you've defined with define-external to do the rest of the work on the result.